# Focus no primeiro campo habilitado do formulário

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Dessa forma eu ativo o focus no primeiro campo do formulário que não é `hidden`:

```
$('form:first *:input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();
```

Como ativo o `focus` no primeiro campo do formulário que não é `hidden` e também não é um campo desabilitado (`disabled`)?

Comment: Caso a resposta lhe tenha sido útil marque ela como correta, assim ajudamos a outros possíveis usuários.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Com `jQuery`

```js
$('form:first *:input[disabled != disabled], [type != hidden] :first').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="hidden">
  <input type="text" disabled>
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Ou

> Use o atributo `autofocus` do `HTML 5`.

```html
<input type="text" autofocus>
<input type="text">
```